# IE svg scaling issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, responsive-design, viewbox

On this [website](http://sonycenter.miterassa.ee/), there are four svg logos in the `.logo-bar` container.
Each of them is put inside of an image tag like so:

```
<div class="logo-bar">
    <p class="logo">
        <a href=""><img src="resources/img/miterassa_logo.svg" alt=""></a>
    </p>
```

The viewBox is set inside of each svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="339.827px" height="84.337px" viewBox="0 0 339.827 84.337" enable-background="new 0 0 339.827 84.337" xml:space="preserve">
```

IE11 on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 does not seem to scale svg's properly.

Every now and then, after initial load or refresh of the page, only some of the logo's are scaled incorrectly.

P.S. I tried to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle but the problem never came.

Comment: Your not using the SVG...you're using an image. If you want to use the SVG **element**, put **that** insde the link instead of the image.

Comment: Using svg in <img> is perfectly fine from a web standards viewpoint, and should work fine (you should file an IE bugreport if it doesn't). Have you tried setting the size of the <img> elements in css and removing the `width` and `height` attributes from the svg root elements?

Comment: We use a lot of SVGs and I've banned the use of `width` and `height` because of problems like this. Stick to `viewBox` in the SVG and have the containing DOM element decide the size.

Comment: So you are saying that the `width` and the `height` in the svg is the problem?

Comment: @ErikDahlström if you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it, as your comment contains the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using svg in <img> is perfectly fine from a web standards viewpoint, and should work fine (you should file an IE bugreport if it doesn't). Have you tried setting the size of the <img> elements in css and removing the width and height attributes from the svg root elements?

The stylerules that apply to the `logo-class` and its children may affect the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set he height and width of the SVG using CSS. I would recommend adding the browser and version to the body tags class using this:

```
// Loop through each of the available browsers
jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function(i, val) {  
if(val != true){
// Render the browser type
        $(document.body).addClass("v"+parseInt(val));
    }
// Render the browser version
    else{
        $(document.body).addClass(i);
    }   
});
```

Then add this CSS:

```
.msie.v9 svg, .msie.v10 svg {
  width: 100%; 
  height:600px; // Add your own height here
}
```